Zscaler certificate error in Android Emulator
We are unable to download some plugins (maven, gradle etc) for android studio. Also We are unable to access internet inside android app in an emulator even after Zscaler is installed CA certificate. Even local host urls also not working. Its throwing SSL error.
android emulator issue - 
1.primary error: 3 certificate: Issued to: CN=www.google.com;Issued by: CN=Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscaler.net) (t)\ ,OU=Zscaler Inc.,O=Zscaler Inc.,ST=California,C=US;   on URL: https://www.google.com/**
2.ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(996) handshake failed

Even zscaler is not allowing to download NPM modules.
Do we need to bypass the zscaler ? if yes, can anybody help us?
Or is there any alternate solution for the above issues.
We have tried adding zscaler certificates in the emulator and tried opening the emulators with the help of dns commands.

Do not install the root CA certificate on Android, that is useless, unless you configure your app to trust user CA certificates. You can include the root CA certificate and trust it in debug builds as described by Google: https://developer.android.com/privacy-and-security/security-config#TrustingDebugCa
